# Filter after the submission of Input Field submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Input field and Submit Button....When i enter some text to input field it started filtering before i submit (Enter the Submit Button). How can i correct that.

**I want to filter after I click the submit button.**

[image]

```js
$(function() {

    var $grid = $('#container');
    $grid.isotope({itemSelector: '.item'});

    var filters = []; // A convenient bucket for all the filter options, 
                      // just so we don't have to look them up in the DOM every time.
                      // (a global array is maybe sort of not the most elegant 
                      // way you could deal with this but you get the idea.)

    // Search event handlers
    $('.quicksearch').on('keyup', function() {
        // debounce removed for brevity, but you'd put it here
        filters[0] = this.value;
        runFilter();
    });
    $('#filter-select').on('change', function() {
        filters[1] = this.value;
        runFilter();
    });
    // and so on if more filters needed

    // The filter itself
    var runFilter = function() {
        $grid.isotope({
            filter: function() {
                if (filters[0]) {
                    // at least some search text was entered:
                    var qsRegex = new RegExp(filters[0], 'gi');

                    // if the title doesn't match, eliminate it:
                    if (!$(this).find('.content-title').text().match(qsRegex)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                if (filters[1]) {
                    // a category was selected; filter out others:
                    if (!($(this).hasClass(filters[1]))) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // etcetera, for any other filters 

                // successfully passed all conditions, so:
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is running with `$('.quicksearch').on('keyup', function() {` everytime a letter is typed. You'll want to change that to when you click the button instead.  So use something like `$('.your-button-class').on('click',function() {` instead.

Comment: yup !...I understand what you are saying....But i dont have any idea about how to do that... so can u please give some demo of that .

Comment: okay, I gave you a breakdown below. because you want both the enter key and the button, I gave you how to do a keyup event for *only* the enter key (which is what you were probably trying to do before). It's simple, and you'll know how to do it now :)  You specifically asked how to do the button click, but you also say talk about the enter/return key as well.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have a `keyup` event. This event type means that every time a key on the keyboard is pressed (and released -- the keyup part), a function will call.

Your code:

```
// Search event handlers
    $('.quicksearch').on('keyup', function() {
        // debounce removed for brevity, but you'd put it here
        filters[0] = this.value;
        runFilter();
    });
```

`$('.quicksearch')` means that when an element with the class quicksearch...

`.on` means when an event happens

`'keyup'` means when a keyboard key is pushed and released

So you have "When the user has the quicksearch selected and they type a letter then run the function". You need to change that to "when the user clicks the button then run the function".

```
// Search event handlers when button is pushed
    $('#id-of-your-button').on('click', function() {
        filters[0] = this.value;
        runFilter();
    });
```

*You can use the ID of the button or the class*

## if you want to also be able to hit enter

You can look for the keyup on the enter key (similar to what you were doing above). And you can just add both of those blocks to your code.

You need to pass the event information to your function by using `function(e)`. And then you can do a conditional check to see if the key that was pushed and released was the "enter" key -- which is `13` --> `if(e.key === 13)`

```
// Search when someone pushes enter in the text field
$(".quicksearch").keyup(function(e){ 
      // Check if the enter key was hit
      if(e.key === 13) {
            filters[0] = this.value;
            runFilter();
    }
});

// Search event handlers when button is pushed
$('#id-of-your-button').on('click', function() {
    filters[0] = this.value;
    runFilter();
});
```

---

### update based on codepen code

There were a couple of errors in your codepen code. You try to apply the filter, but you don't grab the search box's value to apply. And then you forget to pass that search parameter along to the isotope function.

You can fix this by replacing your quicksearch action to:

```
// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.bttn').on( 'click',function() {

    qsRegex = new RegExp( document.getElementById('quicksearch').value, 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope(qsRegex);
});
```

In your code you use $quicksearch.val(), but you assign the variable $quicksearch as the button.

The complete (corrected) code for the javascript in your codepen is as follows:

```
// quick search regex
var qsRegex;
var buttonFilter;

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
    return searchResult && buttonResult;
  }  
});

// bind filter on select change
$('.filters-select').on( 'change', function() {
  // get filter value from option value
  // var filterValue = this.value;
  // use filterFn if matches value
  buttonFilter = this.value;
  //$grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  $grid.isotope();
});

// bind filter on select change
$('.filters-select2').on( 'change', function() {
  // get filter value from option value
  // var filterValue = this.value;
  // use filterFn if matches value
  buttonFilter = this.value;
  //$grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  $grid.isotope();
});

// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('.bttn').on( 'click',function() {

    qsRegex = new RegExp( document.getElementById('quicksearch').value, 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope(qsRegex);
});

// Search when someone pushes enter in the text field
$("#quicksearch").keyup(function(e){ 
     if(e.key === 16 || e.key === 13 || e.key === 'Enter') {
qsRegex = new RegExp( document.getElementById('quicksearch').value, 'gi' );
  $grid.isotope(qsRegex);
     }
});
```

Comment: Here i did What you saud but it not working..... Can u pls try what's wrong in this. https://codepen.io/JOHNakl/pen/qBdyGQr

Comment: I took a look, and solved it. Also, you don't need the denounce any longer, as you won't be using on change but on click.